# how to add multiple OR criteria to my query

Tags: ms-access

I've a few names that I need taken out of my query.

I have tried using `Not Like "..." OR "..."` but it fails. Where to put 'OR' criteria?

Comment: `not in ('aaaa', 'bbbb')` ?

Answer (score 0):

If not a pattern then use: not in(‘name1’,’name2’). Otherwise, in your example, you’re using “or” when you should be using “and”.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple names that you want to exclude, you should use the `Not In("...","...")` syntax.  See the example below:

[image: Not In]

Learn more on [Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-criteria-to-text-values-202548b6-b065-4387-800b-2456a7099bca).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it depends on whether you require **pattern matching**: the [`LIKE` operator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) enables you to match strings using a pattern potentially containing wildcard characters to match an entire range of values.

For example, specifying a selection criteria for a particular field of:

```sql
NOT LIKE "A*"
```

Will cause the selection to *exclude* all records for which that particular field contains a value starting with the letter `A`, this could apply to many different values depending on your dataset.

If you are trying to exclude multiple patterns in this manner, your selection criteria will need to be something along the lines of either:

```sql
NOT LIKE "A*" AND NOT LIKE "B*"
```

or alternatively:

```sql
NOT (LIKE "A*" OR LIKE "B*")
```

---

If, however, you are excluding **exact matches**, then the [`LIKE` operator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) is not required, and you can either use multiple *not equal* [comparison operators](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd#__toc272228349):

```sql
<>"A" AND <>"B"
```

Or, you can use the [`IN` operator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/in-operator-d5a10cdc-cdb2-4854-be22-7abdeb5a3236) in conjunction with the [`NOT` logical operator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd#__toc272228350) in order to specify that the value must not be a member of a predetermined list, e.g.:

```sql
NOT IN ("A", "B")
```